# Get parameters in ssh file passed by Plink in batch

Tags: shell, batch-file, plink

I try to execute a shell file in a remote server using Plink from a Batch file.
Both files are on my local machine.
Everything work but the parameters I try to get back in my shell file :
Here is what I did

Shell file 'test.sh':

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Get parameter 1
echo ${1}
echo Get parameter 2
echo $2
```

Batch file 'test.cmd':

```
@ECHO OFF
plink.exe myuser@MYHOST -batch -ssh -m test.sh param1 param2
```

Result:

```
D:\path>test.cmd
Get Parameter 1

Get Parameter 2

D:\path>
```

Shell commands return empty parameters